# Amazon SP-API Call Limit Multiple Apps

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-selling-partner-api

I'll try keep this as simple as possible I am not the developer of the app.

Currently we have 1 published functioning app linked to the SP-API.

We're working on a new app that also requires the SP-API.

My question.

Is there a limit on the amount of calls you can make per Amazon account or per registered app?

I'm getting the feeling the call limit is based per account (dev account) and not per app registered? As we're hitting limits with the new app in testing.

If anyone can help clear this up for me. I would be grateful.

Hope I made sense

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are limits per account , not per app
see here
https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/usage-plans-and-rate-limits-in-the-sp-api

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).